# LaTeX - wrong figure and table numbering in * environment

Tags: latex

I have a question related to * environment in LaTeX used for spanning figure/table across two columns. It is well known that in this such figure/table is placed on the top of the page. The problem is that the Fig/Tab numbering is not taken into account so for example the two column figure has caption "Fig.4..." and right below it is one column figure with caption "Fig.3" ... which is the wrong order and in this case the figs and tabs should be automatically renumbered right?[problem illutration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtefE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understood the problem, but I would try to put the code for the figure spanning two columns (fig 4 in your image) **before** the code for the figure that it is called fig 3 in your image. That *should* fix it.